# Improve productivity on StackOverflow with lots of functionalities (Chrome extension)

Tags: app, chrome-extensions

[image: Logo]

## StackOverflow Power User

#### About:

**Have you ever felt that you've just wasted time while searching for an answer on StackOverflow ?**

Sometimes it's because you read the accepted answer, then notice that the next one has way more votes than the accepted one. Sometimes it's because you read a question ("Oh yes, it's the same problem as me !") but then discover that there isn't any answer to the question… I've started to develop  solutions to these problems, and come up with a extension with many features that I can't live without since I use it. Every setting can be enabled/disabled through the settings page. I hope some of you will find it as useful as me !

**Here are the main features:**

- Show answers sidebar (with vote counts), and highlight an answer if you have already upvoted it previously
- Show indicator when there's a better answer than the accepted one
- Show indicator when no answer on question
- Auto-scroll to first answer (because you most often find yourself not reading the question)
- Navigation through answers with keyboard arrow keys (left/right)
- Auto expand votes count & Show answer score (in percent) (this feature require 1000 rep minimum)
- Hide the new StackOverflow left sidebar that takes so much space for useless links (personal opinion)

#### Screenshots:

[image: Better answer]
[image: Already upvoted answer]
[image: Options page]

Please find more screenshots on the Chrome Store page.

#### Download / Install:

The extension can be easily installed through the Chrome Store : [StackOverflow Power User](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverflow-power-user/dghoicnlchonhhkccfmjpjconhpajhdg).

#### Platform:

This extension is made for Chrome, and works with all StackExchange websites.

#### Contact:

Feel free to give me any feedback and feature requests in the comments of this post.

#### Code:

This extension is written in Javascript. I didn't open sourced the code yet, but if anybody shows interest, I will be happy to do it. **We can make a really powerful tool with your ideas !**

Comment: feature suggestion: auto-focus on the *Title* input box on the Ask Question page (since you'll almost always be typing in the title first).

Comment: @freginold Thanks for your suggestion, I'll add it as soon as possible :)

Comment: any Update for this tool box???

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 What do you mean? This extension is still maintained.